# How to display the output of the bash script with newlines

Tags: linux, bash, automation, ansible

I have a bash script to check some info that need to execute via ansible

file  ~/Scripts/test/OpenSSL_p.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
echo    "HOSTNAME            : $(uname -n)"
echo -e "OS Type             : $(if [[ -e /usr/bin/lsb_release ]];then echo "$(lsb_release -d|cut -d$'\t' -f 2)";elif [[ -e /etc/SuSE-release ]];then echo "$(cat /etc/SuSE-release | tr "\n" " " | cut -f1 -d"#")";else echo "$(cat /etc/redhat-release)";fi)"
echo -e "OpenSSL Ver         : $(/usr/bin/openssl version)"
echo    "Packages            :"
rpm -qa | grep "^openssl-"
```

ansible playbook

```
---
- name: precheck
  hosts: all
  tasks:
  - script: ~/Scripts/test/OpenSSL_p.sh
    register: results
  - debug:
      var: results.stdout
```

I am able execute the script but but output like this,

```
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************ok: [nfsserver01] => {
    "results.stdout": "HOSTNAME            : nfscluster1\r\nOS Type             : SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2\r\nOpenSSL Ver         : OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019\r\nPackages            :\r\nopenssl-1.1.1d-1.46.noarch\r\nopenssl-1_1-1.1.1d-11.38.1.x86_64\r\n"
}
```

I am looking a output like this

```
HOSTNAME            : nfscluster1
OS Type             : SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2
OpenSSL Ver         : OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019
Packages            :
openssl-1.1.1d-1.46.noarch
openssl-1_1-1.1.1d-11.38.1.x86_64
```

could you please help me to get this ?

Comment: `printf '%b' "HOSTNAME            : nfscluster1\r\nOS Type             : SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2\r\nOpenSSL Ver         : OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019\r\nPackages            :\r\nopenssl-1.1.1d-1.46.noarch\r\nopenssl-1_1-1.1.1d-11.38.1.x86_64\r\n"`

Comment: Note that `printf %b` is the less-buggy way to write what in some bash configurations is `echo -en`. (See [the POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), particularly including the APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections, to understand why `echo -e` _as well as_ `echo -n` should never be used).

Answer (score 1):

Ansible does not render newlines in it's output, it replaces them with `\n` and `\r` instead.

However, the debug module can render lists so you could just use `results.stdout_lines` instead.

```yaml
- debug:
    var: results.stdout_lines
```

Would produce:

```
"results.stdout_lines": [
    "HOSTNAME            : nfscluster1",
    "OS Type             : SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2",
    "OpenSSL Ver         : OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019",
    "Packages            :",
    "openssl-1.1.1d-1.46.noarch",
    "openssl-1_1-1.1.1d-11.38.1.x86_64",
    ""
]
```

**PS.** This only applies to the console output, if you intend to save this to a file for example use `results.stdout` instead.

Comment: Hello @kristian,

Thanks, but still I am getting like this

`
TASK [debug] ************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [nfsserver01] => {
    "results.stdout_lines": [
        "{\"HOSTNAME\": \"nfscluster1\", \"OSTYPE\": \"SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 15 SP2\", \"VERSION\": \"OpenSSL 1.1.1d 10 Sep 2019\", \"Package\": \"openssl-1.1.1d-1.46.noarch openssl-1_1-1.1.1d-11.38.1.x86_64\"}"
    ]
}
`

Comment: added below lines in ansible.cfg, and after getting proper format 
`
    stdout_callback = yaml
    bin_ansible_callbacks = True
`

But color part I am getting like this " [1m[32m " , any option to remove that ?
`
[1m[32m*******OS INFORMATION******(B[m
`

Comment: @vijayedm It seems your script is now producing json, are you using the same `~/Scripts/test/OpenSSL_p.sh` as described in the question?

Comment: If the script is intended to use JSON as its output, you could use `{{ results.stdout | from_json }}` to parse the json string into dictionary. About the color part, i'm not sure what's going on, but it seems your setup has changed and you should update the question accordingly. Both json output and "OS INFORMATION" is something new..